# SQL query to select id's between two years and months

Tags: mysql

i have a table

```
id year month
-------------- 
1  2015  4

2  2015  4

1  2015  5

1  2015  6

2  2015  6

3  2015  6
```

and so on

```
1  2016  3  

2  2016  3

3  2016  3

4  2016  3
```

Now i want all distinct id's from year-month 2015-4 to 2016-3.
i tried between but didn't get desired result.
any help???

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: SELECT * FROM temp where (year between '2015' and '2016') and (month between '4' and '3'); @jens

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT id from temp where str_to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-',1),'%Y-%m-
%d')  between str_to_date('2015-4-1','%Y-%m-%d') and str_to_date('2016-3-31','%Y
-%m-%d');
```

wich converts your values to dates.

Comment: @user2986339 if it helps, feel free to accept my anser